# Symfony "no PHP binaries detected"

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

Ive been just starting to learn Symfony PHP framework, and Ive run into some problems with its configuration.

When trying to create a new project with command line like so:

```
symfony new --full my_project
```

I kept getting a simple error message:

> no PHP binaries detected

and no files were created in the current folder. I searched on the net, and found out that Symfony apparently isnt able to find the location of my **php.exe**, despite it already being set in my system variables. And there was no information about how to properly configure this in Symfony.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: In my case, skipping symfony and using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642155/107625) was the solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out Symfony already contains functions to autodetect installed PHP versions from system variables. The command to fix the Symfony configuration is this:

```
symfony local:php:refresh
```

My next attempt to create a new project work fine after that.
Also, I suspect this error was the result of me installing PHP files **after** installing Symfony.

Comment: Extra note: This solution was found by typing "symfony --help" in command line. Seems that is still a valid option sometimes. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
symfony local:php:refresh
```

doesn't always work.  If your php is not in `[/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /snap/bin]` and a few other locations (check with `symfony local:php:list -vvv`) then symfony won't find it.

I compiled my own PHP from source and installed versions 7.4.20 and 8.0.7 in /home/username/php/7.4 and /home/username/php/8.0.  If I want to use my PHP 8.0.7, then I have to make a symlink because updating the $PATH doesn't help.

```
sudo ln -s /home/username/php/8.0/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
```

This works and symfony finds it.

Answer (score -1):

Follow below *steps*:

- Step 1: [download](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) & Install *xampp* in your system
- Step 2: open the *xampp* folder.
  find php folder and hit enter
- Step 3: copy the path and paste in your system environment
- Step 4 : run

  ```
  php -v
  ```

you are good to go!